# Sum each row and column individually and output it in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, sum

Say I have a matrix with N number of columns of rows I don't know how many and I want to sum every row and output the sum of each row and the same with columns. thanks in advance. How would I write a loop for this in Matlab?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Typically, askers are encouraged to give samples of what they have tried before answerers will be able to assist.  What have you tried?  Could you post a code sample of such here?  You can edit your question by clicking on the "edit" button beneath the tags for matlab and sum.

Answer (score 5):

If all you want is to find a sum of elements in each row/column then [sum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) function is what you need.

To calculate a sum of elements **in each row** of matrix A:

```
sum(A,2)
```

To calculate a sum of elements **in each column** of matrix A:

```
sum(A,1)
```

or simply

```
sum(A)
```

And if you want to print your results:

```
r = sum(A,2);
fprintf('Sum for row%d: %e\n', [1:length(r); r']);
```

If you have problems understanding MatLab syntax - [look at this book](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf).

Comment: yes but I need to do this for N rows and columns So I need to write a loop because I don't know how many rows and columns, any tips?

Comment: @user3000557 It's a matrix you have, is it?

Comment: I am writing a script to load any given matrix, and I want to output the sum of each row and column ie.

Sum for row1: X
Sum for row2: Y
Sum for row3: Z

Comment: The you don't need information about it's size to calculate a sum of elements in each row and column. =)

Comment: Anyway, `size(A)` will tell you its size.

Comment: Ohh you're right not sure what I was thinking... 
How would I be able to output each sum though Like I typed above?
Also won't I need A loop because to sum for N rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write the following for a matrix A of size m rows x n columns

```
% Initialise output vector 
[m n]=size(A);
rowsum=zeros(m,1); % This will be  vector of the sum of each row
colsum=zeros(n,1); % This will be  vector of the sum of each column
for i=1:m
  rowsum(i,1)=sum(A(i,:));
end

for i=1:n
  colsum(i,1)=sum(A(:,i));
end
```

So now you will have an mx1 vector of the sum of each row and an nx1 vector of the sum of each column.